# Duplicate device listed in ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I have a single device connected via usb, but running into an issue where there seems to be a phantom device with same ADB serial number. How can I remove this phantom device?

```
> adb devices -l
List of devices attached
R38M207T2DV            offline usb:1-8 transport_id:672
R38M207T2DV            device usb:1-9 product:beyond2qlteue model:SM_G975U1 device:beyond2q transport_id:627
```

I am running Fedora 34 (Linux)

Comment: did adb restart work?

Comment: Unfortunately not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restarting Fedora seemed to fix it (not sure why).